# Using font icons in qooxdoo svg

Tags: svg, qooxdoo

I want to use font icons in qooxdoo's SVG. How do I add them? For example: **fontFamily: "@webIconfont30/e64b"**, but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you please tell me a bit more as to what qooxdoo code you are writing?

Comment: @webIconfont30/e64b is a Font Icon.My code：var iconFont = new svg.text.Text().set({  
    fontFamily: "@webIconfont30/e64b",
    fontSize: 30,
    fill: "rgb(9, 60, 107)"
   });

Comment: Can you provide more detail. Maybe a minimal working example of what you are trying to do and what you are doing?

Comment: @Tobi Oetiker                                                          
@webIconfont30/e64b is a Font Icon.My code：                                   
 var iconFont = new svg.text.Text().set({  
    fontFamily: "@webIconfont30/e64b",
    fontSize: 30,
    fill: "rgb(9, 60, 107)"
   });

Comment: @Stein Creating a font icon in SVG.

Comment: Please go one step back and try to describe what you want to do. You can also edit your question text and add more information there.The following parts are not clear to me what you want to do: "use font icons in qooxdoo's SVG" as font icons are usable in qooxdoo without SVG and SVG is usable without icon fonts. What did you try until now? Add some code in the question. This is definitely to few information. Look at this comment how much I wrote just to guide you or find out what you want. You could do the same in your question! Please!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, than you want to use glyphs from an icon font as an image for e.g. a qooxdoo button.

You have to use current qooxdoo master as icon font support was added to master a few weeks ago.

It will basically allow you to use an icon glyph in a `qx.ui.basic.Image` which is a subwidget of `qx.ui.basic.Atom` which itself is the base class eg. for `qx.ui.form.Button`.

Please have a look into the documentation at http://www.qooxdoo.org/5.1/pages/development/icon_fonts.html which includes information about the prerequisites like `FontForge` and its python packages and which changes are needed in the configuration of your qooxdoo project.

As there where many questions related to icon font usage in qooxdoo, I've set up a simple example qooxdoo application, using icons from fontawesome, which may guide you on your first steps:
https://github.com/level420/iconfont